# Javascript answer not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

In the code below I made a small script that basically calculates the square root of a number inputted by the user. A pop up shows up and the user inputs his number he wants to work out the square root of. The script works fine as I tested it. My problem is that **a**, the value I want to display is not being displayed. Can someone please point out what the problem is?

```js
function evaluate() {
  var input = prompt("Please enter your input");
  var array = new Array();

  function squareroot(x, y) {
    if (!y) {
      // Take an initial guess at the square root
      y = x / 2;
    }
    var z = x / y; // Divide the inputted number by the initial guess
    var a = (z + y) * 1 / 2; // *Use average of y and z as our new guess
    if (y == a) {
      // *The new guess is the same as the old guess; further guesses
      // *can get no more accurate so we return this guess
      return y;
    }
    // Recursively solve for closer and closer approximations of the square root
    return squareroot(x, a);
  }
  document.writeln("Your calculation is: ");
  document.writeln(a);

}

evaluate();
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Online RPN Calculator</h2>
```

Comment: When do you call `squareroot()`?

Comment: This is very confusing. You're asking the user for a number and putting it in a variable called input but I don't see how "input" is ever passed to squareroot() - when do you call it?

Comment: Dont understand why you have to divide, calculate a z value...?  Just use Math.sqrt(). Plain and simple

Comment: Use document.writeln(squareroot(input)) instead of document.writeln(a);

Comment: What is `var array = new Array();` for, and why is this tagged *arrays*? And *typescript*?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the squareroot function. Changing `document.writeln(a);` to `document.writeln(squareroot(input));` will make it work. Also added a check that an input was given that is not NaN to avoid infinite recursion. `if (!isNaN(input) && input)`

Answer (score 0):

First, you never call `squareroot` function anywhere in your code.

Second, you only get the value from `prompt` but you never use it.

[A simple `prompt()` explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp).

Third, the variable `a` is not accessible by `evaluate` function because it is scoped inside `squareroot` function.

[More about JavaScript scoping here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

**In-depth explanation 1 & 2**

In your `evaluate` function, the first thing you do is defining variable `input` and assigning it to `prompt()` function.

The way prompt function works is that it pauses script execution until the user provide the prompt with an answer.

With this, you can then check whether or not `input` is provided by using `if-else`.

```
if (input !== null){
    // Run this code if `input` is provided.
}
```

or

```
// Stops the function
if (input === null){
    return;
}
```

In the demo below, I use it to run `squareroot` function if its value is provided and use it as the first parameter `x` of `squareroot`.

**In-depth explanation 3**

In your original code, the variable `a` is defined inside `squareroot` function. Therefore, the `evaluate` function cannot see its value because of [scoping](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). Hence the line `document.write(a)` cannot get the value of `a` because to them, `a` is undefined.

Every variable defined in `evaluate` function can be seen by `squareroot` function.

Using this, we can define variable `a` in the `evaluate` function instead of `squareroot` function.

So that `document.write(a)` knows what `a` is.

```js
function evaluate() {
    
    var array = new Array();
    var a = undefined;
    var input = prompt("Please enter your input");
    
    if (input) squareroot(input);

    function squareroot(x,y) {
        if (!y) {
            // Take an initial guess at the square root
            y = x/2;
        }
        var z = x / y;              // Divide the inputted number by the initial guess
        a = (z + y) * 1/2;          // *Use average of y and z as our new guess
        if (y == a) {          
            // *The new guess is the same as the old guess; further guesses
            // *can get no more accurate so we return this guess
            return y;
        }
        // Recursively solve for closer and closer approximations of the square root
        return squareroot(x, a);
    }
    
    document.writeln("Your calculation is: ");
    document.writeln(a);

}

evaluate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following changes please check on this one

Answer (score -1):

as noticed by @n8wrl, you don't provide user input to your function and you have scope issue for 'a' variable.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Squareroot calculator</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 250px;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function squareroot(x, y) {
if (!y) {
          // Take an initial guess at the square root
          y = x / 2;
      }
      var z = x / y; // Divide the inputted number by the initial guess
      var a = (z + y) * 1 / 2; // *Use average of y and z as our new guess
      if (y == a) {
          // *The new guess is the same as the old guess; further guesses
          // *can get no more accurate so we return this guess
          return y;
      }
      // Recursively solve for closer and closer approximations of the square root
      return squareroot(x, a);
  }
  var input = prompt("Please enter your input");
  document.writeln("Your calculation is: ");
  document.writeln(input);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Online RPN Calculator</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should pass your `input` value from user input into the function that you want to make calculation or any other math operation.

Your code seems confusing.